# Как применить массив функций к массиву значений

Tags: python, python-3.x

Есть словарь, где ключ, это значение, которое мы потом вводим через Input, а значение словаря - это название функции. По отдельности каждая функция выполняется для списка (он генерируется случайным образом.) Как сделать, что выполнялись одновременно несколько функций, которые мы вводим через Input и ищем потом в словаре?

Фрагмент кода:

```
functions = {'sum': sum_list, 'multiply': multiply_list, 'join': join_list,
             'union': union_list, 'reverse': reverse_list, 'negated': negated_list,
             'inverted': inverted_list, 'squared': squared_list, 'odds': odds_list,
             'evens': evens_list, 'simples': primenumbers_list}


name = input("Выберите 'sum', 'multiply', 'join', 'union', 'reverse','negated' "
              "'inverted', 'squared','odds', 'evens', 'simples': ")

reducer = functions[name]

result = reduce(reducer, randlist)

print(result)
```

Answer (score 1):

Пример:

```
In [415]: lst = [0, 4, 0, 3, 8, 9, 1, 8, 0, 2]

In [416]: from operator import methodcaller

In [417]: functions = [min, max, sum]

In [418]: list(map(methodcaller('__call__', lst), functions))
Out[418]: [0, 9, 35]
```

---

**UPDATE:**

> Мы вводим 3 значения через input : sum, reverse, evens. Получаем сумму
>   (sum) обратных значений (reverse), четных чисел из списка (even).
>   Значение получаем одно

```
def rev(lst):
    if isinstance(lst, (list, tuple)):
        return [1./x for x in lst]

def evens(lst):
    return [x for x in lst if x%2 == 0]

functions = [sum, rev, evens]

def func(functions, arg):
    if len(functions) == 1:
        return functions[0](arg)
    return func(functions[:-1], functions[-1](arg))
```

проверка:

```
In [126]: lst = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10]

In [127]: sum(1/x for x in lst if x%2 == 0)
Out[127]: 1.1416666666666666

In [128]: func(functions, lst)
Out[128]: 1.1416666666666666
```

Comment: А если мне нужно, чтобы сработали одновременно 2 функции: например, сумма всех обратных значений чисел?

Comment: @Verylucky333, приведите в вопросе небольшой пример входных и выходных данных и примеры 2-3х функций

Comment: Мы вводим 3 значения через input : sum, reverse, evens. Получаем сумму (sum) обратных значений (reverse),  четных чисел из списка (even). Значение получаем одно.

Comment: @Verylucky333, добавил вариант с рекурсивной функцией...